# Does anyone know why Meshmixer does this when I bring a brush to a figure?

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design, meshmixer

Does anyone know why Meshmixer does this when I bring a brush to a figure?

[image]

Comment: I do not know what I am looking at there. You need to be more elaborate in explaining your problem.